# Why ImageDataGenerator is iterating forever?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have just started with Keras and was doing some image pre-processing where I observed that the generator received from `ImageDataGenerator` is being iterated indefinitely in `for-loop`.

```
image_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, rotation_range=45)

train_data_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                               shuffle=True,
                                              target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE),
                                              batch_size=batch_size
                                              )
print('Total number of batches - {}'.format(len(train_data_gen)))
for n, i in enumerate(train_data_gen):
    if n >= 30:
        # I have to add explicit break statement to get out of loop when done with iterating over all the items present in generator.
        break
    batch_data = i[0]
    print(n, batch_data[0].shape)
# TRY to access element out of bound to see if there really exists more than 30 elements.
print(''.format(train_data_gen[32]))
```

**Output**

```
Found 2935 images belonging to 5 classes.
Total number of batches - 30
0 (150, 150, 3)
1 (150, 150, 3)
2 (150, 150, 3)
.
.
.
29 (150, 150, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-aed377bb98f7> in <module>
     13     batch_data = i[0]
     14     print(n, batch_data[0].shape)
---> 15 print(''.format(train_data_gen[32]))

~/.virtualenvs/pan_demo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     55                              'but the Sequence '
     56                              'has length {length}'.format(idx=idx,
---> 57                                                           length=len(self)))
     58         if self.seed is not None:
     59             np.random.seed(self.seed + self.total_batches_seen)

ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 32, but the Sequence has length 30
```

**Question**

1. Is this the way `ImageDataGenerator` is meant to work? If so, Can I avoid `if n >=30` checking part somehow?
2. Am I missing something while preparing a generator which leads to such behavior?

Keras version: `tf.keras.__version__`  ---> `2.2.4-tf`
Tensorflow version: `tf.VERSION` ---> `1.13.1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, `train_data_gen` will generate data batch by batch infinitely.

When we call `model.fit_generator()`, we specify the `train_data_gen` as generator, and set `steps_per_epoch` (should be `len(train_data)/batch_size`). Then the model would know when a single epoch is finished.

Comment: Does this mean that when the ImageDataGenerator is terminated it restarts automatically?

Comment: I just checked with some few sample images and yes, it restarts automatically passing again the same images when it terminates

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator):

```
for e in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', e)
    batches = 0
    for x_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
        model.fit(x_batch, y_batch)
        batches += 1
        if batches >= len(x_train) / 32:
            # we need to break the loop by hand because
            # the generator loops indefinitely
            break
```